# how to sum different values of time type in sql table

Tags: mysql

my  query :

```
 SELECT (
 `total_hours`
)
FROM work_details
WHERE  `employee_id` =  '28'
AND DATE
BETWEEN  '2012-02-01'
AND  '2012-02-01'

LIMIT 0 , 30
```

// Which takes total hours worked for a given employee in given date from database table work_details

result:

```
total_hours
            02:27:29
            00:13:56
            03:03:49
            00:00:03
            00:30:20
            01:04:13
```

//result shows the times an employee worked in a given date,I need to get the total of these values to find total working hour in a given date.

how to get sum of these values in a field???

if i use sum(total_hours) result would be

```
sum( total_hours ) 
67870
```

and that is not correct.I require it in time type itself.

And i have one more help needed, this query worked because i gave same date for the BETWEEN clause.

```
DATE
    BETWEEN  '2012-02-01'
    AND  '2012-02-01'
```

But i need to calculate total working hours of days in a given range , say

```
DATE
    BETWEEN  '2012-02-01'
    AND  '2012-02-29'
```

Since a given date has multiple total hours entry , i need get total hours for each distinct day.Help??

Comment: no , it not working, if i use sum(total_hours) result would be 
sum( `total_hours` )
67870  and that is not correct.I require it in time type itself. Thank You :)

Comment: Is total_hours a varchar field?

Comment: More info about why `SUM(time)` does not work in MySQL here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12108

Answer (score 4):

try this (taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`total_hours`))) ... -- rest of your query
```

Comment: haha :) Its working :) Thanks Again :) I have one more doubt , can you help? Ill Update the question,

Comment: still related to this question? if no, you'd better create another question to avoid mixing different problems in one question.

Comment: SELECT date,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`total_hours`))) AS total
FROM work_details
WHERE  `employee_id` =  '28'
AND DATE
BETWEEN  '2012-02-01'
AND  '2012-02-29'
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE   This Worked  for me ,Thank you:)

Comment: seems like you've figured the answer yourself, an accept wouldn't be rejected :)